# python how to rename a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, object

So I am currently working on a battle sim for a school project in which two tanks will battle each other.
every tank has to have the possibility of having multiple gun objects.
so I made a method to let the user create guns but I want to make sure that every time I call this method the generated list will get the name saved in the `gunListName` variable. is there a way to do this cause I can't find out how to do this.

Here is the method I'm talking about:

```
 def createguns(self,):
    gunList = []
    gunListName = input("please input the name of the tank that will use these guns: ")
    gunNumber = input("how many guns do you wish to give your tank? ")
    for x in range(int(gunNumber)):
        gunName = input("please input the name of your gun: ")
        gunRange = input("please input the range of your gun in Meters(example: 1000 CM would be 1KM range): ")
        gunMinRange = input("please input the minimum range of your gun: ")
        gunDamage = input("please input the damage value of your tank: ")
        gunReload = input("please input the reload time of your gun")
        gunName = Gun(gunName,gunRange,gunMinRange,gunDamage,gunReload)
        gunList.append(gunName)
    return gunList
```

Comment: Declare your variable outside your method and you will be sorted

Comment: Your `createguns` functions should be responsible for creating guns only, it's the responsibility of the code that calls it to do whatever it wants with it.

Answer (score 0):

DO like this

```
def createguns(self):
    gunList = []
    gunListName = input("please input the name of the tank that will use these guns: ")
    gunNumber = input("how many guns do you wish to give your tank? ")
    for x in range(int(gunNumber)):
        gunName = input("please input the name of your gun: ")
        gunRange = input("please input the range of your gun in Meters(example: 1000 CM would be 1KM range): ")
        gunMinRange = input("please input the minimum range of your gun: ")
        gunDamage = input("please input the damage value of your tank: ")
        gunReload = input("please input the reload time of your gun")
        gunName = Gun(gunName,gunRange,gunMinRange,gunDamage,gunReload)
        gunList.append(gunName)
    return gunList, gunListName

gunList,name = createguns()
print(name)
```